# Alacarte menu editor not working

Tags: lubuntu, menu, alacarte

lubuntu 20.04
Alacarte menu editor doesn't work for me.  The changes I make are not saved, or not as I make them. For example, I added a link to alacarte itself in the main menu, but the link appeared in the Other submenu.  Same thing with any other app links I create;  they all end up in Other.  Code::Blocks, I created a folder C++ under Programming and put the CB link there, but it appeared directly under Programming.
Also, invoking Alacarte from the menu doesn't work;  only typing its name in a terminal does, and I get a message,

> [code] Gtk CRITICAL: 28:13:52.528: gtk accel label set accel closure :
> assertion 'gtk accel group from accel closure (accel closure) != NULL'
> failed [/code]

Which, as a programmer myself I recognize as an assert that should not be present in software compiled for release.
Anyways, maybe lubuntu is forcing its will on the menu...
I suspect it's some bad setting;  maybe it's accessing the wrong menu file.  But the program has NO preferences or settings of any kind.  Any idea how to make it work?
Sorry I can't figure out the text formatting here.

EDIT:
I've just been informed I'm running an incompatible program.
I honestly have no idea what qt5 is, or LXQt for that matter.   I assumed anything Synaptic showed me would work in my system.
I guess this changes my question to ...
**how do I edit my menu?**

Comment: You've got me confused, `alacarte` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/alacarte) is a GNOME menu editor, GNOME being GTK3 based; where as Lubuntu is LXQt is Qt5 based so has nothing at all to do with GTK3.  LXQt can set GTK3 themes only (see appearance in (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/search.html?q=gtk3&check_keywords=yes&area=default) but you've got me confused by your post.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question.

Comment: End user programs use libraries, GNOME & GIMP share a *toolkit* called GTK (originally GTK+ to represent GIMP+GNOME).  LXQt uses Qt (version 5) or the Q *toolkit* as is found in Android phones, many windows programs. It's a library/toolkit system that is part of the software stack between end-user programs and the base operating system. As a *programmer* I assumed you'd realize the theory of software stacks sorry, but by using the wrong stack the changes made for GTK have ~no influence at all on Qt based systems like LXQt, KDE or other Qt based programs.

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS uses the LXQt desktop, use `neofetch` to get some details, or `lxqt-about --version`.  `synaptic` is a GTK program, so was included in Lubuntu releases that used LXDE (or GTK2; GNOME is GTK3), but it was replaced with `muon` as it's Qt based and thus more efficient. They'll both run equally (`synaptic` just needing more RAM as it cannot use libraries already in your memory so additional ones are loaded), but the changes they make impact packages on your disk/system, so the results are equal.

Comment: As a programmer I loved algorithms and solving intricate problems, but hated libraries.  I was once working on a 3d engine and I wrote the whole vector, matrix and quaternion thing from scratch because I could not stand libraries.  Right now I feel like writing  a menu editor, maybe in assembler...

Comment: Currently there is no Qt based app to change a LXQt menu (see https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/255), so it's all changes made via editor to files on your system manually...

Comment: Too many acronyms, I'm totally lost.  Are you saying I should be using muon rather than synaptic?

Comment: Okay, this is going to be my first job, then:  write a qt menu editor.

Comment: Because `muon` is more efficient with your memory, that's why it's recommend and thus included by default. If you've got memory/RAM to spare you're welcome to use `synaptic` as it's known to you as it's your choice (ie. I mentioned the result was the same anyway). Synaptic uses GTK3 libs meaning they need to be loaded into memory prior to use, `muon` requires Qt5 libs (already in memory as used by the LXQt desktop)...

Comment: :)  on Qt Menu editor idea....  If you need help, I'll suggest the #lubuntu( or -devel) channel on IRC (freenode), or via Telegram. (https://lubuntu.me/links/ ; a *bot* links IRC with telegram).  LXQt is found on OFTC (https://lxqt.github.io/)

Comment: What about debian "menu"?  I'm not sure how to tell if it uses qt5 or gtk3 or what...